# cannot open snap apps - "cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_9Cf5Oo//dev: no such file or directory"

Tags: 18.04, mount, snap

I've been unable to use any of my `snap` applications. Every time I try to open one I get the above mentioned error.

```
$ discord
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_yoTt35//dev: No such file or directory
```

This started after my Ubuntu's boot dropped to (initramfs) busybox prompt which required me to manually run the `fsck` command.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, with `snap`

```
$ snap version
snap    2.43.3
snapd   2.43.3
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-91-generic
```

I tried removing and reinstalling GIMP, but now I'm unable to install it back. It gives me error when it runs its install hook.

```
$ sudo snap install gimp
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run install hook of "gimp" snap if present (run hook "install": cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_1w00X1//dev: No such file or directory)
```

I'm unable to use any snap packages because of this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same problem for a long time, and finally managed to solve it. The problem was because of my own setup, so it might not be applicable in you case, but maybe it'll point you in the right direction.

The problem seems to be that snap doesn't like having different things symlinked to different devices.

In my case, the problem was that my `/var` partition really was a symlink to `/mnt/var`. I had the correct mount point `/var` set in `/etc/fstab`, but of course fstab followed the symlink as well, and mounted the device to `/mnt`.

For me, the solution was to just rename the symlink with `sudo mv /var /var.BAK`, create an empty mount point with `sudo mkdir /var` and reboot. `/etc/fstab` now mounts the device directly to `/var`, and snap works like a charm.

So, try and do `ls -l /` and check that `var` is a directory and not a symlink (which would read for instance `var -> /mnt/var`). Also  check that other directories snap might use (`/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/var/snap`, for instance) are real directories and not symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/snap /tmp/snap.rootfs_7keS1C//var/snap: Permission denied`

I had /var_snap linked to /var/snap (made with `ln -s`) becouse of the low space on `/var` partition.

Solution:

1. `sudo unlink /var/snap`
2. `sudo mkdir /var/snap`
3. `sudo mount --bind /var_snap /var/snap` - check if snap application starts after this
4. Add line to the `/etc/fstab`:

```
/var_snap /var/snap auto  defaults,nofail,nobootwait,bind 0 2
```

5. reboot